# Error while trying to connect to SQL Server - localhost

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have checked the instance name, auto close is set to true, allow remote connections on the server is checked. The server is running when I open the SQL Server configuration manager. I have even rebooted. I have created this db the same way as all others. I use Entity Framework and have checked the names in the `web.config` and they match. This is the default connection string from the wizard - I use for testing before I deploy. I just can't think of anything else to check to figure out why it won't connect. Working inside SQL Server everything is fine.

Here is the general error.

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL >Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is >correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Shared >Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)*

Config:

`connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=.\SQL_1;attachdbfilename=&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL_1\MSSQL\DATA\A_db.mdf&quot;;integrated security=True;connect timeout=10;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the connection string used ?

Comment: Keep in mind this connection string was self generated for local host, the server one matches the standard. I moved to the server due to the strange errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me preface this answer by saying that proper setup of a SQL instance is not as easy as Microsoft would like you to think with the entity framework.  It's a little bit involved and requires that you put your DBA hat on for a little bit.

The error you have indicates that the web instance is attempting to connect to the SQL server using Windows Integrated Security.  This will work fine if (a) the windows user that the process is running as (which can be configured in IIS) is authorized to log on to the SQL server and has a valid login in the database and (b) if the SQL server is on the same machine or in the same domain as the IIS server.

In light of this, I recommend using SQL Server authentication.  If you need to know how to do this, I recommend searching for "SQL Server Authentication setup" - here is an article that I found which might help you set this up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx

In general, I recommend taking the following actions:

1. Connect to the sql server using MS SQL Management Studio.
2. Permanently attach your database, then use the [`Initial Catalog` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237410%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) on your connection string rather than `AttachDbFileName`
3. Then set up your login username and password on the SQL server, and create a login in the database for it.
4. Make sure your login can only execute the stored procedures you want it to execute. Deny it access to running sql statements.

You will also need to add the username and password to your connection string, and set IntegratedSecurity=false.

Let us know how things go once you get your SQL server set up properly.

Comment: I will get started on that right away. I will get back when I can - busy week. This is my third Db with Entity. The first two deployed fine and this one has been a headache. I reviewed the previous ones to check for differences. I am relatively good at searching for answers, but this one has been exhausting. I appreciate all the help so far.

Comment: My site that is connected to my DB is hosted in IIS7 by my hosting company - not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: When I open SSMS for the DB I see the sa and other login(which I am using), It has the _Sql Server Auth_ grayed out under status - does that help any? Pemissions is set to Grant, login is enabled.

Comment: You need to create a restricted user for your SQL server, then go to the User Mapping (on the screen you describe) and map a user into your database with public, db_denydatareader, db_denydatawriter checked.  Then, you will have to go in and set explicit permissions for the user in your database (under [DBName]-->Security-->Users). It's beyond the scope of the question for me to explain how here, you'll have to do some googling :-)

Comment: error: _cannot alter user_ - when I try to map the user. thanks for your continued help!

Comment: More info: I make the Db on the server - empty. I make a local Db on local computer for testing. When it is done I make a backup and restore the server Db from the backup. If this a bad practice let me know - I only know by playing around and what I find in searches. Could this have caused the issue? Though the last two worked fine?

Comment: I am also not finding any info on permanently attaching a Db - your #2 step.

Comment: It sounds like your db is already attached. And you need to run `EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', '[Username]'` (where you substitute the proper username) after doing your backup/restore to a different server procedure.

Comment: _User does not have permission to perform this action._ I'll have to check but I don't think I have permissions to the sa account - I have tried to login before.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your provider code cannot find the SQL Server.  If you have checked the server instance name (it should be `<yourLocalServer>\SQL_1`), then it could be the `attachdbfilename=` parameter, as this is a really unreliable way to specify the database to connect to (you should be using the Database Name, not the file name), because there are about a hundred reasons that the file name could change that have nothing to do with your application.

Comment: Current: Data Source=tcp:{myhostingsiteaddress}.com;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=dbname;Pwd=password;                        I am getting a weird error:  _Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'._

Comment: I also get this error when changing the con string: _Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'._

Comment: Which of these two errors are you getting? (They are incompatible), and at what point are you getting it?

Comment: The last one is the current, not sure what I did to fix the first??? I have tried search that error too. The initial page loads, the error comes when the Entity model is opening.

Comment: Yes well, "*Could not find stored procedure ...*" is not (normally) a connection error, so you must be connecting OK now.  You should check that SQL Server and the database for that stored procedure.

Comment: I don't see any stored procedure.